# Find $p$ such that $(p-1)$ has many small divisors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm looking for a prime $p$ such that $(p-1)$ has many "small", preferably distinct, divisors.

I tried framing the question as solutions for $p$ to the system,
\begin{align*}
\phi(p) = 0 \mod p_i \quad \text{for } i=1\cdots n
\end{align*}
where $p_i$ is the i'th prime.

Does anybody know any efficient ways to solve this or have some literature that touches this topic?

Comment: For example, like $p=M_{17}=2^{17}-1$? Then $p-1=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 17\cdot 257$. Have a look for literature in cryptography (smooth numbers), e.g., Pollard's $p-1$ method etc.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, I'm of cause looking at \phi(p) = 0 \mod p_i

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HighlyCompositeNumber.html or https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial_prime

Comment: Number theorists call $\,p-1\,$  [smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number). Searching on that should reveal much of interest.

Comment: (Although "friable" is much better terminology than "smooth".)

Comment: If you want $p-1$ to be divisible by your favorite numbers $d_1,d_2,\dots,d_k$, it's probably both reasonably fast and reasonably optimal to compute $L=\mathop{\rm lcm}[d_1,d_2,\dots,d_k]$ and then examine the numbers $L+1,2L+1,3L+1,\dots$ in turn, testing each one until you find a prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do much better than http://oeis.org/A018239, which has the primes that are one more than a primorial.  In particular $200560490131$ is one more than the product of all the primes up to $31$.  The next one is rather large
$$171962010545840643348334056831754301958457563\\
589574256043877110505832165523856261308397965147\\
9555788009994557822024565226932906295208262756822\\
275663694111$$
You can find more from http://oeis.org/A005234 which gives the highest prime to multiply before adding $1$ to get a prime.